# Why is giving me true the regular expression [^%()*+-\/=?@[\\]ªº´`¿'.]* with the comma (,)?

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a problem with that regular expression  `[^%()*+-\/=?@[\\]ªº´`¿'.]*` .

I want to avoid the characters inside. the regular expression it is working but when I set something like DAVID, SC I can save the form because it has a comma but this character it is not inside the regular expression.

Could you help me please?

Comment: I am testing in http://rubular.com/

Answer (score 2):

You are not accounting for the special meaning of `-` inside a character class `[.....]`.

You must either place the dash at the very end, or else escape it with a backslash:

```
[^%()*+\/=?@\[\]ªº´¿'.-]*
```

In your original regex, `+-\/` disallows any characters between `+` and `/` in the ASCII table; these are the comma, dot and dash. Your example input contains a comma so the regex did not match all of the input at once.

I have also fixed the escaping for the `[]` characters from `[\\]` to `\[\]`, which I presume was a mistake.

Comment: You can include an unescaped close bracket inside a character class if it is the first character: `[][^%()*+\/=?@ªº´¿'.-]`

Answer (score 1):

Because you're using `*` in `[^%()*+\/=?@[\\]ªº´¿'.-]*` with line start/end anchors. `*` means match 0 or more of preceding group/pattern in character class and your regex can even match an empty string.

Use this regex:

```
^[^%()*+\/=?@[\\-]ªº´¿'.]+$
```

**PS**: Hyphen `-` should be either or first OR at last position in character class to avoid escaping.

[**Rubular Demo**](http://rubular.com/r/1yGa4VgaMg)

Comment: No, `*` inside square brackets is a literal character.

Comment: @Jon Yes, but he has * after the brackets.

Comment: @Jon: Of course I know that. I am not taking about this `*` OP's regex is: `[^%()*+-\/=?@[\\]ªº´¿'.]*` which has a `*` outside character class.

Comment: @Jon, he meant the * at the end, on the outside of the brackets

Comment: I don't see how that is relevant. Either `*` or `+` at the end makes absolutely no difference with the example input. The **real** issue is the unescaped dash which has been edited into the answer as a footnote after I brought it up. That is totally misleading.

Comment: @Jon: Well now you're saying a different thing. `[^%()*+\/=?@[\\]ªº´¿'.-]*` without `^` and `$` can even match an empty string. That is what I means and wrote in my edited answer

Comment: @anubhava: I am saying the exact same thing. The OP does not explicitly mention it but **obviously** the regex is enclosed inside `^` and `$` because if it were not, it would still match the input "DAVID, SC" (two matches). And the OP complains that it doesn't match. And again, `^` and `$` has nothing to do with the difference between `*` and `+`.

Comment: @Jon: In not-so-good worded problem and unclear regex we can only draw our inference from it. Not everybody's interpretations will be same.

Comment: I got the solution from here, my final regular expression is [^%()*+\-\/=?@[\\]ªº´`¿'.]+ I had to set backslash before -. Anyway with + is working

Comment: anubhava, I am working with MVC4 and it is not necessary to set ^ at the begginning and $ at the end